# How to use Firebase User Authentication with an Auxiliary Server

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

The architecture for my infrastructure is as shown below:

```
----------         ----------         ----------
| client |<--------|  sync  |<--------| server |
----------         ----------         ----------
     |                                    ^
     |                                    |
     --------------------------------------
```

I have an iOS client that listens to the Firebase sync layer, but pushes writes via HTTP requests to a Node/Express server, which does some computationally intensive stuff and pushes the results to the sync layer. Now I can make sure the iOS client only reads data it has permissions for in Firebase, but I don't know how to make sure the client can't send requests to the server to initiate writes to other people's data. Is there a good way to make sure authentication with Firebase extends to this setup?

Comment: You could pass the auth token of the user from their client to your server when they push their write. Then the server can pass it along to Firebase either with `auth.authWithCustomToken` (JavaScript SDK) or in the `auth` URL parameter (REST API).

Comment: Another alternative, which avoids the need to deal with auth at the server end, removes the need for a REST API, and generally turns your *server* into a *script*, is to write the users' requests into Firebase and read them at the server using a [queue pattern](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue). By this method, you can use [security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) to enforce auth and your server can assume anybody who writes to the specified path is authenticated correctly and simplify its task considerably.